# Passing a parameter into setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

What is the deal with passing a parameter from a function into a `setTimeout` call? Why is `path` here returning `undefined`? And what should I do instead?

```
$('.curatorSpace').bind('click', function() {
    var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
    setTimeout(function(path) {
        if($('#curatorRibbon').hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')){return false}
        runOverlay(path);
    }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need/must pass anything in there. `path` is a *free variable* and closured by the anonymous function you pass into `setTimeout`. Hence, you can just access it.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if($('curatorRibbon').hasClass('ui-draggable-dragging')){return false}
    runOverlay(path);  // path gets resolved in the parent context
}, 100);
```

actually, by declaring `path` as formal parameter of that anonymous function, you've overwritten that variable lookup process through the scope chain. Just get rid of that.

Comment: To further clarify -- when `setTimeout` calls the function you have provided, setTimeout does not pass parameters to the function.

Comment: @StephenP This is usually true. However, in browsers other than IE, additional parameters could be added after the delay (100 here) which would be passed to the function. This could be handy if you wanted to use the same function for multiple timeouts, but it has much less value here in particular. Details are available at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout .

Comment: @Jeff - yes thanks for further clarifying, and someday IE may catch up (I haven't been checking IE10 yet)